# How to set CLASSPATH to use Leap Motion in Processing?

Tags: java, processing, classpath, leap-motion

I am trying to use the Leap Motion tracking device in Processing 4. I added the LeapJava library but whenever i try to run my project i get this error message:

```
Native code library failed to load. 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no LeapJava in java.library.path:
```

Since i am a beginner i do not understand or know how i can add the LeapJava.jar to my class path. I hope someone can explain how i can do this so my project will run.

I already tried following these two tutorials but i cannot seem to get it working:

https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/v2/java/devguide/Project_Setup.html

https://developer-archive.leapmotion.com/documentation/java/devguide/Leap_Processing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the Darius' [Leap Motion Processing Library](https://github.com/nok/leap-motion-processing) ?

You should be able to install it via **Processing > Sketch > Import Library... > Add Library...** > which opens **Contribution Manager** (from there you can search "leap")

[image: Leap Motion for Processing library logo: the pocessing logo and Leap Motion logo next to each other]

```java
import de.voidplus.leapmotion.*;

LeapMotion leap;

void setup() {
  size(800, 500);
  background(255);
  
  leap = new LeapMotion(this);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  
  for (Hand hand : leap.getHands ()) {
    hand.draw();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately your answer gives me the same error when i run the project. Does this work for you? If so, how did you set your classpath variable?

Comment: On my system (currently Win11) the library examples run just fine. 
What OS are you using ? That error can occur if the native (c++ java bindings) library doesn't exist (or that path to it is incorrect). As far as I can see, the library supports Linux 32/64 bit, OSX X (Intel) 64 bit, Windows 32/64 bit, but there are no java bindings for Linux ARM (e.g. Raspberry PI) or OSX on ARM (e.g. newer M1 macs). Doing a quick search I see multiple people [complaining on a forum post about the lack os M1 support](https://forums.leapmotion.com/t/problem-with-mac-m1/16002)...

Comment: ... I've also spotted a potential workaround for M1 using Python [in this post](https://www.brettwarne.com/posts/leap-m1/). (Not 100% sure, but it might be possible to potentially use [Python Mode for Processing](https://py.processing.org/) instead of Processing Java (or other Python Processing ports. Worst case scenario you can have a basic Python script that uses `python-osc` to simply send the data over to Processing (e.g. using [oscP5](https://sojamo.de/libraries/oscP5/) in Processing))

Comment: Your method worked on WIndows 10, unfortunately not on my M1 Mac. Thank you for your answers! Really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on trying to get the Leap Motion to work on my Mac Pro M1. I tried @George Profenza his answer and it worked on Windows 10.

After this i had connection issues with the Leap Motion camera because i had to install an older SDK. I Finally got everything working after this article on the Leap Motion forum. Apparantly i had to dive into the Leap folder structure and manually install some extra drivers.

https://forums.leapmotion.com/t/leap-motion-controller-wont-connect-for-2-3-1-but-will-for-4-0-0/8517